# preg_match_all don't extracted arabic words in PHP

Tags: php, regex

i make this code to check text and print all banned words , banned words list Containing Arabic words and English words But do not be extracted and printed Arabic words only English words, where the error?

```
    $banwords = "megaupload.com|alferdawsway.com|مرحبا|هالو";
    $bwords = explode("|", $banwords);   
    $text = "BLA BLA BLA مرحبا megaupload.com هالو alferdawsway.com BLA BLA BLA ";  
    $matches = array();  
    $matchFound = preg_match_all("/\b(" . implode($bwords,"|") . ")\b/i",   $text ,   $matches  );  
    if ($matchFound)  
    {  
    $words = array_unique($matches[0]); 
    $allwords =  implode(',', $words) ;
    print_r($allwords);
    }
//output : megaupload.com,alferdawsway.com
//but it must be : megaupload.com,alferdawsway.com,هالو,مرحبا
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try again with `u` identifier.

Look it usage:

`preg_match_all("/\b(" . implode($bwords,"|") . ")\b/ui", $text, $matches);`

Comment: @omardealo, you're doing something wrong. Just use "/ui" instead of "/i" at the end of your regexp. I have checked with PHP 5.4, and it does work (it finds four words, two of them Arabic).

Comment: i do like you said but don't working with me `preg_match_all("/\b(" . implode($bwords,"|") . ")\b/ui",   $text ,   $matches  )`

Comment: i try code and working on php file on another web , i think the problen on Encoding So code does not recognize the Arabic letters , How can i fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

your coded page file (where you write code) have **convert into encoding type UTF-8** . then it will works.

for convert:

open the file in notepad++ , and from **"encoding"** menu covert file

Comment: if multiple file is included then **main file have to convert**